# Virtual Hyper-V Windows 2008 R2 Server Web Console

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, interface

Where and How can I enable the [Virtual Hyper-V Windows 2008 R2 Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-main.aspx) Web Console?

The IIS is only set up as the **default content**, nothing more than that.

Just to avoid using **Remote Connection** every time I need to start / end a VM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none. To manage Hyper-V from say a Windows 7 client you simply install the appropriate [Remote Server Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en) (RSAT) and use the included Hyper-V Management Console to connect to your Hyper-V server. The RSAT pack is available for Vista, Server 2008 and 2008 R2 as well.

There is at least one [ongoing project](http://hvwm.codeplex.com/) to develop a third party web console but it doesn't look very useful yet. If this is something people would be interested in however I've thought about doing it recently - though if it can't be run properly on the pure Hyper-V Server it doesn't feel as cool, requiring a separate web server (unless it's bundled with a text-based UI for initial VM setup/management ^^)

You can also just simply [use the local (R2 only) or remote powershell console to manage VMs](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/storage-management/administer-microsoft-hyper-v-command-line-cli.html) thanks to James O’Neill's neat Powershell library for this.

```
New-VM DBSRV01
Start-VM DBSRV01
```

Comment: I never been fan of powershell but got the remote server to work, though I would really prefer a vmware web console alike: http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-05-20_1051.png

Comment: Yeah well, Hyper-V is basically made to be managed by SCVMM instead -  a bit like managing vmware vsphere with the web console isn't the best way, using virtual center is.